# $f ≡ g \iff f^{-1}[N \setminus \{0,1\}] = g^{-1}[N \setminus \{0,1\}]$ equivalence class being a set that is at most countable.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

We define an equivalence relation $≡$ in the set $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ as follows:
$$f ≡ g \iff f^{-1}[N \setminus \{0,1\}] = g^{-1}[N \setminus \{0,1\}]$$
for $f, g \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$

Check whether there is a function $f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ such that its equivalence class is a set that is at most countable.

---

What I know for sure is that if a function is reversible it means it is a bijection. I don't know how to make out any equivalence classes out of simple inversion of functions. Is't that tue that if a reverse functions are equal, then original functions are equal as well?

Edit:
Is it true that:
$$f ≡ g \iff f^{-1}[N \setminus \{0,1\}] = g^{-1}[N \setminus \{0,1\}] \implies f ≡ g \iff f[\{0,1\}] = g[\{0,1\}]$$
???

Comment: Hint: An two functions which take only the values $0$ and $1$ are equivalent.

Comment: Just for clarification, $$f^{-1}[A] = \{x \in \mathbb{N} : f(x) \in A\}$$ doesn't require $f$ to be invertible.  The important fact here is that at least one of $f^{-1}[\{0,1\}]$ and $f^{-1}[\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}]$ will be infinite

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ok, but those in the exercise precisely do not take values of $0$ and $1$. Or is that their domain?

Comment: With respect to the question in your edit, I assume you mean $$\begin{align*}f\equiv g &\iff f^{-1}[\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}] = g^{-1}[\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}] \\ &\iff f^{-1}[\{0,1\}] = g^{-1}[\{0,1\}],\end{align*}$$ in which case, yes, this is true.  It follows directly from $$f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \implies \mathbb{N} \setminus f^{-1}[\{0,1\}] = f^{-1}[\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0,1\}]$$ (try proving this)

Comment: But do note that Brian said $f^{-1}[\{0,1\}] = g^{-1}[\{0,1\}]$, not $f[\{0,1\}] = g[\{0,1\}]$ as your current edit has. Your version is not equivalent to $f\equiv g$.